# Django templates and Static in different folders

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to start a new project. In the tutorial it says I need to store the templates and static folders in the project folder. My project folder name is twjp. But for some reason if is store the the templates folder in twjp folder it doesn't work. it works only if I store it in the twjp/twjp folder. Below is my settings.py

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)


TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'templates')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

"domainname/rango/ --> Doesn't work if I store templates in twjp/templates it works only if I store it in twjp/twjp/templates"

Answer (score 0):

Tell me what ever you specs ie, Which version of django,python etc.

I hope this works for you, if not tell me i will update my answer too.

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static"),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'templates')
                 )
```

This should your templates work with twjp/templates and twjp/static and not twjp/twjp.